# Vite v3.2.5 use app.js instead of app.mjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, es6-modules

I use VueJS version 2 with Vite v3.2.5 and when I load my website I get this error in Firefox:
Loading of the module from ".../build/app.mjs" was blocked due to an unapproved MIME type ("application/octet-stream").

CSS/SCSS is working and I have only problems with the app.js/app.mjs.
Is it possible to change the output of my file from app.mjs to app.js?

This is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
const path = require('path')
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            hotFile: 'public/widget.hot',
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/scss/index.scss'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: true
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        },
        dedupe: [
            'vue'
        ]
    },
    alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
    },
    build: {
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        lib: {
            input: {
                app: "./resources/js/app.js"
            },
            formats: ['es'],
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/app.js'),
            output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename: 'bundle.js'
            },
            name: 'bundle',
            fileName: 'app'
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['vue'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    vue: 'Vue',
                },
                //format: "esm",
                inlineDynamicImports: false,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

I have this in my blade.php file:
@vite('resources/js/app.js')

Does anyone how to fix it?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What server software are you using? You can fix this most easily by adding a mime type mapping for `.mjs` to `text/javascript`.

Comment: I have only a webhosting and I can't make changes on the server. Is it then also possible to add a mime type?

Comment: What type of web hosting? cPanel? Plesk? Some other type of control panel?

Comment: Yes, I think it's Plesk but a little bit modified by the provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the mime type for `.mjs` files in the Plesk control panel (based on their [docs](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003017653-How-to-configure-MIME-types-for-a-domain-in-Plesk)):

### If this is a Linux server

1. Log in to Plesk.
2. Go to **Domains** > `YOUR DOMAIN NAME` > **Apache & nginx Settings**.
3. Next to MIME types, select the **Enter custom value** option button.
4. Add a line that says: `text/javascript .mjs`.
5. Save your changes.

### If this is a Windows server

1. Log in to Plesk.
2. Go to **Domains** > `YOUR DOMAIN NAME` > **Hosting Settings** > **IIS Settings**.
3. Go to the **MIME Types** section.
4. Add a line that says: `text/javascript .mjs`.
5. Save your changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server settings and I can't make changes there